# Sonar visual studio bootstrapper is not working

Tags: sonarqube, fxcop, bootstrapper, sonarqube-4.5

I have changed csharp sonar runner properties to execute with visual studio bootstraper but fxcop arent applied.

When i run normaly fxcop detect several rules non-compliances.

The code:

**sonar-project.properties default**

```
# Note: It is not recommended to use the colon ':' character in the projectKey
sonar.projectKey=org.example.csharpplayground
sonar.projectName=C# playground
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

# Disable the Visual Studio bootstrapper
sonar.visualstudio.enable=false
sonar.sources=
sonar.exclusions=obj/**
sonar.modules=CalcAddTest,CalcMultiplyTest,CalcDivideTest,CalcSubtractTest
#,MyLibrary

# Configure the main and/or test sources of each project
CalcAddTest.sonar.tests=.
CalcMultiplyTest.sonar.tests=.
CalcDivideTest.sonar.tests=.
CalcSubtractTest.sonar.tests=.
MyLibrary.sonar.sources=.

# Code Coverage
sonar.cs.ncover3.reportsPaths=coverage.nccov
sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=results.xml
sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths=dotCover.html
sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=VisualStudio.coveragexml

# Unit Test Results
sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=TestResults/*.trx

# Required only when using SonarQube < 4.2
sonar.language=cs

# FxCop
CalcAddTest.sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly=CalcAddTest/bin/Debug/CalcAddTest.dll
CalcMultiplyTest.sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly=CalcMultiplyTest/bin/Debug/CalcMultiplyTest.dll
CalcDivideTest.sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly=CalcDivideTest/bin/Debug/CalcDivideTest.dll
CalcSubtractTest.sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly=CalcSubtractTest/bin/Debug/CalcSubtractTest.dll
#MyLibrary.sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly=MyLibrary/bin/Debug/MyLibrary.dll
```

**sonar-project.properties with visual studio**

```
sonar.projectKey=TEST:org.example.csharpplayground
sonar.projectName=TEST:C# playground
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.sources=.
sonar.visualstudio.enable=true
sonar.visualstudio.skipIfNotBuilt=true
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=CSharpPlayground.sln
```

Comment: Are your FxCop rules all registered in the C# configuration in Sonar?

Comment: Yes, when i enter to view all profiles i have in C# i see fxcop rules profile actived by default

Comment: Please add the logs of the analysis

Comment: Hi, i dont know cause but now with the same configuration sonar detect rules non-compliances... i will try to find the cause.